# multiple tsne (and pca) transforms on one plot

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, tsne

I'm reviewing a paper, in which the researcher fitted different t-sne transforms and plotted them on one plot, showing clusters in 2-d after dimensionality reduction (t-sne).
Each cluster was fitted separately.

Since the transforms were fitted separately- it looks to me that this plot is faulty- there is no meaning at looking over them together.

Can you find a meaning for such a plot?

(additional info-
let x be an embedding (d=100) calculated from 10 different input types. resulting in 10 embeddings of dimension 10.  Then, the researcher transformed them to 10*2 through 10 tsne different transformations and plot the 10 groups in 2d, showing 10 clusters)

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand how the $x$ axis was created. What do you mean by $d=100$? In general, the axis in $t$-SNE have little to no meaning so combining them has little to no justification.